# filter is not iterating over all the elements in the array. Why?

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I would like to filter through a returned week array and group together the same day with the same type of event and viceversa, another new array grouped by the same day but different type of event

```
// I have created a static array with all the events
const types = ["Event", "Food", "Other", "Real Estate"];

// this is what the filtered days array returns
```

[image: filtered array by days]

So far this is what I was able to do:

```
const filteredEqualTypes = types.map((type, i) =>
   filteredDays[i].filter(filteredDay => filteredDay.type === type)
);
```

...but it stops before Thursday by returning an empty array even if should returns an array with 2 objects because on Thursday there are 2 equal events

[image: filtered events]

Comment: Can you share the JSON of your original `filteredDays` array of arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using `filteredDays[i]` in your map, i.e. **accessing the `filteredDays` array by index**. This means that `Event` will only apply to Mondays, and `Food` will only apply for Tuesdays, so on and so forth. You want to perform the filtering in the entire `fitleredDays` arrays instead of a specific entry/item, i.e. `filteredDays[i]`.

Since you only have 4 types, that means that on top of that, you will only performing filtering up till Wednesday—that is why you don't see any more entries beyond that.

So, as per your requirement, that you want to **group the events based on type**, then you can do the following:

1. Go through all the types (you've already done that correctly)
2. For each type, you want to go through the **entire `filteredDays` array**
3. In each iteration, you filter as usual
4. Once the collection is returned, you want to flatten it, because you are returning the original structure (events grouped by days). You want a flattened array of events, not grouped by days. This can be done by using [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Updated code:

```
const filteredEqualTypes = types.map((type) => {
  // Returns a nested array
  const entriesMatchingType = filteredDays.map((filteredDay) => {
    return filteredDay.filter((day) => day.type === type);
  });

  // Use Array.prototype.flat to flatten the nested arrays
  return entriesMatchingType.flat();
});
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const types = ["Event", "Food", "Other", "Real Estate"];
const filteredDays = [
  [{
    day_of_the_week: 'MONDAY',
    type: 'Event',
  }, {
    day_of_the_week: 'MONDAY',
    type: 'Event',
  }],
  [{
    day_of_the_week: 'TUESDAY',
    type: 'Food',
  }, {
    day_of_the_week: 'TUESDAY',
    type: 'Other',
  }, {
    day_of_the_week: 'TUESDAY',
    type: 'Food',
  }],
  [{
    day_of_the_week: 'WEDNESDAY',
    type: 'Real Estate',
  }, {
    day_of_the_week: 'WEDNESDAY',
    type: 'Other',
  }],
  [{
    day_of_the_week: 'THURSDAY',
    type: 'Other',
  }, {
    day_of_the_week: 'THURSDAY',
    type: 'Other',
  }],
  [{
    day_of_the_week: 'FRIDAY',
    type: 'Real Estate',
  }],
];

const filteredEqualTypes = types.map((type) => {
  const entriesMatchingType = filteredDays.map((filteredDay) => {
    return filteredDay.filter((day) => day.type === type);
  });
  return entriesMatchingType.flat();
});
console.log(filteredEqualTypes);
```

---

In fact, I would go one step further and suggest you use a dictionary instead. That is because your event types are unique anyway, and it's easier to reason about:

```
const eventsByType = {};
types.map((type) => {
  const events = filteredDays.map((day) => {
    return day.filter((event) => event.type === type);
  }).flat();
  eventsByType[type] = events;
});
```

```js
const types = ["Event", "Food", "Other", "Real Estate"];
const filteredDays = [
  [{
    day_of_the_week: 'MONDAY',
    type: 'Event',
  }, {
    day_of_the_week: 'MONDAY',
    type: 'Event',
  }],
  [{
    day_of_the_week: 'TUESDAY',
    type: 'Food',
  }, {
    day_of_the_week: 'TUESDAY',
    type: 'Other',
  }, {
    day_of_the_week: 'TUESDAY',
    type: 'Food',
  }],
  [{
    day_of_the_week: 'WEDNESDAY',
    type: 'Real Estate',
  }, {
    day_of_the_week: 'WEDNESDAY',
    type: 'Other',
  }],
  [{
    day_of_the_week: 'THURSDAY',
    type: 'Other',
  }, {
    day_of_the_week: 'THURSDAY',
    type: 'Other',
  }],
  [{
    day_of_the_week: 'FRIDAY',
    type: 'Real Estate',
  }],
];

const eventsByType = {};
types.map((type) => {
  const events = filteredDays.map((day) => {
    return day.filter((event) => event.type === type);
  }).flat();
  eventsByType[type] = events;
});

console.log(eventsByType);
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the explanation, one more little thing, I would like to group it by event and also by the same day, if on tuesday there is just one event like "other" i do not want it to be together with wednesday[other] and thursday[other] but as a single element. Is this possible?

Comment: If you still want to nest them by day, then just remove the need to use `.flat()`.

Comment: amazing, thanks again, I have marked your answer as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over types, you need to iterate over `filteredDays`, to map all days and not just the number of days equal to the length of valid types

```
const res = filteredDays.map(day => day.filter(val => types.includes(val.type)));
```